# Using Selenium with Python and PhantomJS to download file to filesystem

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, download, phantomjs

I've been grappling with using PhantomJS/Selenium/python-selenium to download a file to the filesystem.
I'm able to easily navigate through the DOM and click, hover etc. Downloading a file is, however, proving to be quite troublesome. I've tried a headless approach with Firefox and pyvirtualdisplay but that wasn't working well either and was unbelievably slow. I know That CasperJS allows for file downloads. Does anyone know how to integrate CasperJS with Python or how to utilize PhantomJS to download files. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

Despite this question is quite old, downloading files through `PhantomJS` is still a problem. But we can use PhantomJS to get download link and fetch all needed cookies such as csrf tokens and so on. And then we can use `requests` to download it actually:

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('page_with_download_link')
download_link = driver.find_element_by_id('download_link')
session = requests.Session()
cookies = driver.get_cookies()

for cookie in cookies: 
    session.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
response = session.get(download_link)
```

And now in `response.content` actual file content should appear. We can next write it with `open` or do whatever we want.

Answer (score 12):

PhantomJS doesn't currently support file downloads. Relevant issues with workarounds:

- [File download](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10052)
- [How to handle file save dialog box using Selenium webdriver and PhantomJS?](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12283)

As far as I understand, you have at least 3 options:

- switch to `casperjs` (and you should leave python here)
- try with headless on `xvfb`
- switch to normal non-headless browsers

Here are also some links that might help too:

- [Selenium Headless Automated Testing in Ubuntu](http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/)
- [XWindows for Headless Selenium (with further links inside)](https://gist.github.com/textarcana/5855427)
- [How to run browsers(chrome, IE and firefox) in headless mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289425/how-to-run-browserschrome-ie-and-firefox-in-headless-mode)
- [Tutorial: How to use Headless Firefox for Scraping in Linux](http://scraping.pro/use-headless-firefox-scraping-linux/)

Comment: It seems file download capability has since been added to PhantomJS (including comments to that effect in the [thread you linked to](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10052)). However, I am not sure this is exposed in an easy-to-use way in Selenium.

Answer (score 3):

My use case required a form submission to retrieve the file. I was able to accomplish this using the driver's `execute_async_script()` function.

```
 js = '''
    var callback = arguments[0];
    var theForm = document.forms['theFormId'];
    data = new FormData();
    data.append('eventTarget', "''' + target + '''"); // this is the id of the file clicked
    data.append('otherFormField', theForm.otherFormField.value);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', theForm.action, true);
'''

for cookie in driver.get_cookies():
    js += ' xhr.setRequestHeader("' + cookie['name'] + '", "' + cookie['value'] + '"); '

js += '''
    xhr.onload = function () {
        callback(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send(data);
'''

driver.set_script_timeout(30)
file = driver.execute_async_script(js)
```

Answer (score -1):

Is not posible in that way. You can use other alternatives to download files like wget o curl.

Use firefox to find the right request and selenium to get the values for that and finally use out of to the box to download the file

```
curlCall=" curl 'http://www_sitex_org/descarga.jsf' -H '...allCurlRequest....' > file.xml"
subprocess.call(curlCall, shell=True)
```