# R Selenium right click download file

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, rselenium

Using the `RSelenium` package, I'm trying to right click a link to download a file.

My application requires me to provide a log in with a password, which works fine, but this simple application demonstrates my current obstacle.

Consider this attempt to download an excel file of football rankings.

```
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium::checkForServer()
RSelenium::startServer()

remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")

remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("http://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/rankings/wr.php")


xls_link <- remDr$findElement("css selector", 
                              "#export-xls")
```

Next I hover the mouse over the link I need to download

```
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = xls_link)
```

When I take a screen shot it's apparent that the code has worked thus far (that is, the link is underlined)

[image]

Why doesn't the following:

```
remDr$click(1)
```

Download the file?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with something similar and it seems it is not a Selenium issue but a PhantomJS one. Apparently, it's kinda hard to download files with PhantomJs. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755713/using-selenium-with-python-and-phantomjs-to-download-file-to-filesystem) and [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10052). Perhaps you can simply use Firefox and it will download the file to the default Downloads folder.